# AttributeError: 'Animate' object has no attribute 'FuncAnimation' despite trying every suggestion

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributes

I have been searching for hours about why this could be happening but to no avail.

I have a class to define the animation process:

```
class Animate:

def __init__(self, I, q, w):
    --variable setup---
    self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    self.ax = p3.Axes3D(self.fig)
    self.verts_plot, = self.ax.plot([],[],[],'b')
                 . . .

def anim_init(self):
    self.ax.axis([-3,3,-3,3])
    self.verts_plot.set_data([],[],[])
    return [self.z_trace_plot, self.y_trace_plot, self.verts_plot]

def anim_func(self, frame, t_conv):
    step = t_conv
    sol = self.simulator.solve_step(frame*t_conv, step)
    self.verts_plot.set_data(self.vertices[:,0],self.vertices[:,1],self.vertices[:,2])
    return [self.z_trace_plot, self.y_trace_plot, self.verts_plot]


def make_animation(self,t_1, t_conv):
    tvals = np.linspace(0, t_1, t_1*10 + 1)
    fig = plt.figure()
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, anim_func)
    plt.show()
    return anim
```

I then run these functions under the **name**=='**main**' check at the bottom with

```
 animation = Animate(I, q_0, w_0)
 my_animation = animation.make_animation(10, 1)
```

I then get told:

```
 File "animation.py", line 81, in <module>
   self.my_animation = animation.make_animation(10, 1)
 File "animation.py", line 62, in make_animation
   self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, anim_func)
AttributeError: 'Animate' object has no attribute 'FuncAnimation'
```

Comment: I see no definition anywhere for `FuncAnimation`.  What is it, and where is it defined?

Comment: you seem to be overloading your `import matplotlib.animation as animation`  (I assume, please include the full import statement with your question) with a local variable called `animation`. Try renaming your `Animate` instance something else than `animation`

Comment: you were absolutely right thats fixed it thanks very much - I stupidly cut my imports out because stack told me i had too much code in my question. Thanks

Comment: Is this your entire program? If not, it may help to show your full code.